# Why my browser (chrome) having time lag to display the changes done on CSS?

Tags: css, apache, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, xampp

I am working on HTML and CSS in VS code. Additionlly, I am using Xampp to run the Apache server hence displaying my results on localhost.

Whenever I am doing some changes to my external CSS, the changes are not being reflected on the browser instantly.

I am not doing any code error as after refreshing the browser again after 10-15 minutes, the changes which I made start reflecting.

Why am I getting this time lag on browser respones to catch the changes in css file from VS code?

I have tried ctrl+F5 and also disabled cache in Right-click+inspect+network.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the problem of the browser.Did you try any other browser or did you try updating google-chrome if there is an update or try reinstalling chrome.
if that doesn't work try reinstalling xampp. If that doesn't work i don't anything else.

Edit:Try Clearing Browser Data or if there is a big image file linked in the external css that might cause the problem